# Google markers click do function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I got an google maps on my site which are great at the moment, except i would like to call an function for javascript when the marker is clicked. this is the google code for the marker:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latingZee, 
              map: map, 
              title:"Hello World!",
              icon: ZeeImg,
          })
```

And i would to start the next action to be used when the marker is clicked

```
$('.toggler').live('click',function(){
              $(this).parent().children().toggle();  

          });
```

Is this possible?

Comment: How will the marker know which item with class .toggler you're supposed to simulate the click for?

Comment: Well i got an different class for every toggle, so i got .toggler and .toggler2 etc.

Comment: Really in that case you should use an ID instead of a class, to differentiate them, if they're unique.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $('.toggler').click();
});
```

but I'm not sure about mixing jQuery and Google API code in the same place.

Comment: totally fine to mix as long as you don't try to use a jquery listener.

Answer (score 1):

Simple marker click like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    $('.toggler').parent().children().toggle();  
});
```